# $A_{2}^{T} + A_{2} < 0$ for $A_{2} =(A_{1}A_{0}^{-1})^{\alpha}A_{0}$?

Tags: lie-groups

Given are two matrices $A_0, A_1$, whose symmetric part is negative definite:

$A_{0}^{T} +  A_{0} < 0$,

$A_{1}^{T} +  A_{1} < 0$

How could one proof that: $A_{2}^{T} +  A_{2} < 0$ for

$A_{2} = (A_{1}A_{0}^{-1})^{\alpha}A_{0}$ and $\alpha \in [0, 1]$?

Comment: Sorry, what is $(A_1A_0^{-1})^\alpha$?  If $A_1A_0^{-1}$ has positive spectrum, then I know how to define this.  But in general, it will be massively multivalued.  But perhaps there is a definition I don't know.

Comment: In my case $A_{1}A_{0}^{-1}$ has positive spectrum. Then it can be written: $(A_{1}A_{0}^{-1})^{\alpha}=\mathrm{e}^{\alpha \mathrm{log}(A_{1}A_{0}^{-1})}$.

Comment: So I assumed.  But it would be best to specify this.

Comment: I mean, if $A_0= \epsilon + i$ and $A_1 = \epsilon - i$, for $\epsilon$ small and positive, then $A_1A_0^{-1} = -1 - 2\epsilon i + o(\epsilon)$.  Here by $\epsilon$ I mean $\epsilon \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & \\ & 1\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ and $i = \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} & 1 \\ -1 & \end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$.